How Sending Raw Data works (focus on gRPC and TorchSErve)?
I am working with gRPC and Protobuf, I want to make an rpc request to to TorchServe gRPC api, this is the service definition in the .proto (https://github.com/pytorch/serve/blob/master/frontend/server/src/main/resources/proto/inference.proto)
service InferenceAPIsService {
    // Check health status of the TorchServe server.
    rpc Ping(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (TorchServeHealthResponse) {}

    // Predictions entry point to get inference using default model version.
    rpc Predictions(PredictionsRequest) returns (PredictionResponse) {}

    // Streaming response for an inference request.
    rpc StreamPredictions(PredictionsRequest) returns (stream PredictionResponse) {}

    // Bi-direction streaming inference and response.
    rpc StreamPredictions2(stream PredictionsRequest) returns (stream PredictionResponse) {}
}

... and this is the PredictionRequest message:
message PredictionsRequest {
    // Name of model.
    string model_name = 1; //required

    // Version of model to run prediction on.
    string model_version = 2; //optional

    // Input data for model prediction
    map<string, bytes> input = 3; //required

    // SequenceId is required for StreamPredictions2 API.
    optional string sequence_id = 4; //optional
}

I iwll be sending my model's data in the input.second field, which as you see is expecting bytes (Raw Data) I am new to this so I do not know how it works. Lets say I have a multidimentional numpy array, and I encoded into bytes and, build my request by setting PredictionREquest.input.insert('string', my_encoded_in_bytes_array) and send it, is it going to know how to interpret it? I am not providing any encoding information. Can someone please help me? Thank you.
Also, if you have an idea of how TorchServe converts data before it gets to the BaseHandler feel free to share. I have taken a look at the code but I am not sure.
I know that my confusion comes from lack of knowledge on the topic, so I welcome any article or resouce recomendation.
